# Header overlaps the sticky box when scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, position

I want to have a Sidebar that sticks on the window when you scroll but stop scrolling when it hits the footer. I have managed to get it working to a good level, it's only a small problem that I can't seem to be able to solve.

Test it live here: http://meeped.co.uk:93/portfolio/ambition-world.html

everything is fine until you scroll, the sidebar sticks to the top of the page hidden behind the fixed header as well. How to make it not hidden behind the Header? and to be position to the right place? also is there anyway we can Animate it so it is a bit smooth?

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <title>LOAI Design Studio</title>
        <meta name="description" content="LOAI Design studio"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="">

        <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=10.0, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/core.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/fixes.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width : 1030px)" href="../assets/css/tablets-landscape.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width : 770px)" href="../assets/css/tablets-portrait.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width : 500px)" href="../assets/css/phone.css"/>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--Header--><header>
            <div id="headerWrapper">
                <div id="headerContent">

                    <div id="headerLogo">
                        <a href="../index.html"><img alt="loai design studio logo" src="../assets/elements/logo.png"/></a>
                    </div>

                    <nav><ul id="mainMenu" class="snapjs-expand-left">
                        <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
                        <li><a href="../about.html">About Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul></nav>

                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <!--Website Content--><div id="Page">       

            <div id="secondHeader">
                <a class="secondHeader-menuButton" href="#">Menu</a>
                <p id="logo-smallScreen">LOAI Design Studio</p>
            </div>

            <div class="wrapperB">
                <div id="portfolio-projectPage" class="content">

                    <div class="imagesGrid">    

                    <p>Logo</p>
                    <img alt="Ambition World Logo Design" src="images/ambition-world-logo-mockup.jpg">

                    <p>Business Card &amp; a Mug Mockup</p>
                    <img alt="Ambition World Business Card Design" src="images/ambition-world-bussiness-card-mockup.jpg">       

                    </div><div class="detailsBox">

                        <h3>Ambition World General Trading </h3>
                        <p>This Logo and business card designed for my Dad's Dubai based company.</p>

                        <p><strong>Skills:</strong> Graphic Design</p>
                        <p><strong>Date:</strong> 2013</p>
                        <p class="shareButtons"><strong>Share This Project On:</strong>  
                        <a href="http://facebook.com/LOAI.Design.Studio" class="facebook" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 'facebook-share-dialog', 'width=626,height=436'); return false;"><span>Facebook</span></a>    
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter" target="_blank"><span>Twitter</span></a></p>

                        <div>
                            <a onclick="history.go(-1);">Go Back</a>
                            <a href="#">Next Project</a>
                            <a class="scrollup">Go Up</a>   
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--Footer Section--><footer>
            <div id="footer-sectionA">
                <div class="footerContent">
                    <h3><strong>Want to get started?</strong></h3>
                    <p>I offer free, no-obligation consultation, will review your project <br> &amp; discuss ways to achieve your goals within your budget &amp; time frame.</p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" href="http://www.vcita.com/meeting_scheduler?o=YnV0dG9u&amp;s=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.loaidesign.co.uk%2F&amp;v=1afd868e">Schedule an Appointment Now</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>          
            <div id="footer-sectionB">
                <div class="footerContent">
                    <p>Copyright ©2012 LOAI Design Studio. <br> All rights reserved.<a href="../terms-and-conditions.html">Terms &amp; Conditions.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </footer>
        </div><!--The End Of The Page-->

        <!--Scripts Links-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/libraries/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/slider.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="../assets/libraries/modernizr.js"></script>
        <!--GoSquared Scripts-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var GoSquared = {acct: "GSN-035800-K"};
          (function(w){
            function gs(){
              w._gstc_lt = +new Date;
              var d = document, g = d.createElement("script");
              g.type = "text/javascript";
              g.src = "http://d1l6p2sc9645hc.cloudfront.net/tracker.js";
              var s = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
              s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
            }
            w.addEventListener ? w.addEventListener("load", gs, false) : w.attachEvent("onload", gs);
          })(window);
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
/*Portoflio Project Page*/
#portfolio-projectPage{
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
}

.imagesGrid, .detailsBox  {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.imagesGrid {
        width: 65%;
    }

    .imagesGrid img{
        border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }                                           

    .imagesGrid p {
        border-top: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
        padding-top: 8px;
        margin: 10px 0;
    }   

    .imagesGrid p:first-of-type {
        border-top: none;
        padding: 0 0 10px 0;
        margin: 0;
    }   

.detailsBox {
        width: 347px;
        position: fixed;
        margin-top: 28px;
        padding-left: 30px;
    }

    .detailsBox p {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        margin: 10px 0;
    }   

    .detailsBox p, h3 {
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }

    .detailsBox a {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }       

    .detailsBox p:last-of-type {
        border-bottom: 3px solid #E8E8E8;
        margin: 0;
    }   

    .detailsBox div {
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
        padding: 15px 0;
        text-align: center;

        border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    }

    .detailsBox div a{
        background-color: #E8E8E8;
        padding: 10px 14px;
        cursor: pointer;

        border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .detailsBox div a:hover{
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background-color: #456087;
    }

    .detailsBox div br {
        display: none;
    }

    .shareButtons a {
            margin-left: 3px;

            -moz-transition: none;
            -ms-transition: none;
            -o-transition: none;
            transition: none;
        }

    .shareButtons a span {
            display: none;
        }
```

And Finally The JavaScript bit:

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.scrollBottom = function() {
        return $(document).height() - this.scrollTop() - this.height();
    };

    var $StickyBox= $('.detailsBox');
    var $window = $(window);

    $window.bind("scroll resize", function() {
        var gap = $window.height() - $StickyBox.height() - 10;
        var visibleFoot = 255 - $window.scrollBottom();
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

        if(scrollTop < "auto" + 10){
            $StickyBox.css({
                top: (200 - scrollTop) + "px",
                bottom: "auto"
            });
        }else if (visibleFoot > gap) {
            $StickyBox.css({
                top: "auto",
                bottom: visibleFoot + "px"
            });
        } else {
            $StickyBox.css({
                top: 0,
                bottom: "auto"
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: oh, sorry! lol fixed.

Comment: I asked because it's the same in your code...

Comment: apologizes for my spelling mistake, it's been a bad night trying to get this working and I have been trying lot of things, will change it. Thanks

Comment: What does `if(scrollTop < "auto" + 10)` is supposed to do ?

Comment: I say that because `"auto" + 10` is a string : `auto10`. So this condition will always return false. Try to change your condition like so : `if(scrollTop < 80)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if(scrollTop < "auto" + 10)` will always return false as `"auto" + 10` is a string.
Replace this :

```
if(scrollTop < "auto" + 10){
    $StickyBox.css({
        top: (200 - scrollTop) + "px",
        bottom: "auto"
    });
}
```

by this :

```
if(scrollTop < 80){
    $StinkyBox.css({
        top: (130 - scrollTop) + "px",
        bottom: "auto"
    });
}
```

I changed the values to get the desired behaviour.

Also, in your last condition, make it `top: 80` to be below the header :

```
else {
    $StinkyBox.css({
        top: 80,
        bottom: "auto"
    });
}
```

**Edit :** enhanced code

```
var gap = $window.height() - $StinkyBox.height() - 10;
var visibleFoot = 255 - $window.scrollBottom();
var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

if(scrollTop < 50){
    $StinkyBox.css({
        top: (130 - scrollTop) + "px",
        bottom: "auto"
    });
}else if (visibleFoot > gap - 100) {
    $StinkyBox.css({
        top: "auto",
        bottom: visibleFoot + "px"
    });
} else {
    $StinkyBox.css({
        top: 80,
        bottom: "auto"
    });
}
```

Comment: It worked! thanks, however when it reach the footer, it overlaps it then flips up to where is suppose to be - any idea how to fix that? please

Comment: is there anyway you can show me how can I add smooth animation to it? please.

Comment: Well, it take time but the trick is to use `animate()` instead of `css()`. Good luck ;)

Comment: I have noticed a problem, when the screen size is small it loses the functionality, what can play part in that? any advice please.

Answer (score 1):

When scrolling, an in-line style of

```
top: 0px;
```

gets applied to the element class .detailsBox

this is why it appears to 'stick' to the header, kind of hard to play around with it when it's not in a fiddle, but from a brief overlook, you're altering the css top value alot here:

```
if(scrollTop < "auto" + 10){
    $StickyBox.css({
        top: (200 - scrollTop) + "px",
        bottom: "auto"
    });
} else if (visibleFoot > gap) {
    $StickyBox.css({
        top: "auto",
        bottom: visibleFoot + "px"
        });
} else {
    $StickyBox.css({
        top: 0,
        bottom: "auto"
    });
}
```

This shouldn't be necessary? You already have a margin-top of 28px on that element, and it's position is fixed, so it'll always be in the correct position.

Comment: I have tried to change it, but it does nothing - the same problem.

Comment: What happens if you remove it? It shouldn't be necessary ^^

Comment: Just did you are right it's not really necessary, but it fixed nothing.

Comment: actually, just tried it again, when I delete it, it overlaps the footer

Comment: Really? When i remove the top value, it seems to return to the place you want it http://imageshack.us/a/img29/6897/5skz.jpg

Comment: I had deleted the whole snippet, but now just deleted the value bit and it worked yes! however it overlaps the footer for only an eye blink and then go up - any ideas? http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/191/ubiu.jpg/